# Insert image in prompt in angular , and put an initial value for my prompt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prompt

I wanted to know if it's possible to insert an image in a prompt in javascript i'm using angularjs , and put an initial value for my prompt ?

```
$scope.Myfunction = function (i) {

bootbox.prompt(SOURCE OF THE IMAGE ??, function (r) {
            if (r === null) return;

    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But please be more descriptive when asking a question.  Always post your effort what you have done till now,

Comment: Sorry , i edited my post , thank you @SurjeetBhadauriya  Do you how an idea how t help me ?

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing is that JavaScript does not allow to add images on prompt and alert box. You can only add text or take input from that.

**But, as you asked for AngularJS. So here is the answer. Yes it's possible.**

1. Use uib-modal 
   http://embed.plnkr.co/4VcNom/
2. Use sweet alert
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngsweetalert